# HtmlEncode string within IQueryable without altering bound data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, data-binding, iqueryable

I'm binding an ASP.NET control to the result of a LINQ query.  I'd like to HtmlEncode one of the properties of the contained objects before binding to the control, but I want to do it without altering the data because I do a DataContext.SubmitChanges() later on.  How can this be done?

Code that won't work:

```
var ds = (from s in dc.SearchResults
    orderby s.datetime descending
    select s)
    .Take(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecentItemQty"]));
foreach (SearchResult sr in ds)
    sr.Query = Server.HtmlEncode(sr.Query);
rSearches.DataSource = ds;
rSearches.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy me.  I just need to HtmlEncode it within the OnItemDataBound() event.

Answer (score 2):

Your could encode it when you do your binding...

```
<asp:YourDataBoundControl>
    <ItemTemplate>
        Query: <span><%# Server.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("Query")) %></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:YourDataBoundControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have two copies of the data:

```
from s in dc.SearchResults
orderby s.datetime descending
select new {
  Original = s,
  Encoded = Server.HtmlEncode(s.Query)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode('string');

Both are valid but the one above is available anywhere within an application easier than loading up HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode.